# Login to instagram using python

Tags: python, authentication, beautifulsoup, web, instagram

I am trying to login to instagram.Here is my code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import *
payload = {
    'action': 'login',
    'username': 'name',
    'password': 'pass'
}

with session() as c:
    c.post('https://www.instagram.com/login.php', data=payload)
    response = c.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/edit/')
    print(response.headers)
    print(response.text)
```

unfortunately it doesn't seem to log me in. I get:

```
lt-ie8 lt-ie7 not-logged-in client-root
```

Any solutions would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: before testing the login, can you check the page first if you successfully accessed instagram? There's a possibility that you got an error especially if they implemented anti-bot features.

Comment: I tried to go to 'https://www.instagram.com/login.php', page doesn't exist.

Comment: You haven't passed any headers. Have you tried including them?

Answer (score 3):

you can get idea to implement this from here

[Logging to Instagram using Python requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22941347/logging-to-instagram-using-python-requests)

my code for login to instagram

```
import pdb
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/')
dom = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*')

pdb.set_trace()
username = dom.find_element_by_name('username')
password = dom.find_element_by_name('password')
login_button = dom.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="_qv64e _gexxb _4tgw8 _njrw0"]')

username.clear()
password.clear()
username.send_keys('your username')
password.send_keys('your password')

login_button.click()
driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login')

if 'logged-in' in driver.page_source:
    print 'Logged in'
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need an API key in order to make calls to the Instagram API, also I don't think you can directly log in someone like that.

Answer (score 0):

I would recomend you to use [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) and a [PhantomJS webdriver](http://phantomjs.org/documentation/).